# How to connect phonegap api project with new Facebook SDK

Tags: iphone, facebook, cordova

Can we connect phonegap api project with new Facebook SDK? If so, then how?

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question but there is now the Phonegap Facebook plugin: https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect

hope that helps,
-fs

Comment: That plugin may have worked once, but it's badly maintained garbage now, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

http://www.pushittolive.com/post/1239874936/facebook-login-on-iphone-phonegap

Comment: I tried it, its not working..... Jsut displaying 'loading.....'. Should we add 'New facebook SDk' to the project?   It you have ant sample code, can u plz give me...

Comment: I would assume you'd have to at least supply a reference to the iPhone SDK. Otherwise why don't you look at using the http://graph.facebook.com/ instead?