# How can I use the mobileweb facebook connect API with phonegap?

Tags: android, facebook, blackberry, cordova

I'm trying to integrate Facebook into my Phonegap application that is going to be deployed for both Android and Blackberry devices.  As there is only a plugin available for Android I need to go down the standard Facebook connect mobileweb route.  However I cannot redirect back to file:// (Phonegap) so I'm wondering if anybody has come up with an alternative solution?

I was wondering if it was possible to redirect to a separate hosted site I setup that would store the access code and then get the Phonegap application to subsequently interrogate for the access code to then use with Facebook API calls?

Comment: Can you show a code sample? I'm not understanding what the reasoning is for redirecting back to "file:// (Phonegap)"

Comment: Simon,  did you check out this post?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604274/how-to-connect-phonegap-api-project-with-new-facebook-sdk

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

Use the JavaScript API, enable "Website" and "Mobile Web" under your app settings at https://www.facebook.com/developers

You will need some sort of publicly accessible page available that you can put in your settings, but because you are using this app in a standalone manner, the site doesn't ever need to be used.

Also, have a "Login" button when using the JavaScript API.  You might run into popup blocker issues if you programmatically try to open Facebook's login window.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the InAppBrowser of PhoneGap to call the Mobile Web auth stuff? See http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser

To get started with Facebook Login, have a look here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/getting-started-web/